# How to solve Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a method `jsonProductItems()` which return a map with String key and value.

```
public Map<String, String> jsonProductItems() throws IOException {
        List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> productsAndIdentifier = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Item item : example.getItems()) {
            products.add(item.getName());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
            productsAndIdentifier.put(indetifier.get(i), products.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        return productsAndIdentifier;
    }
```

When in the same class in other method  I want to do a matrix. When value from matrix is equal with a key from map returned by `jsonProductItems()` method, will print value of this key. But at line `if(("" + sumByRemainder.get(i) + j).equals(entry.getKey()))` have `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1`. How to solve this problem? And why in this case it appear?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
            System.out.print(sumByRemainder.get(i) + " ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    System.out.print(" " + j);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else {
                    indetifier.add("" + sumByRemainder.get(i) + j);
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : jsonProductItems().entrySet()) {
                        if(("" + sumByRemainder.get(i) + j).equals(entry.getKey())){
                            System.out.println(jsonProductItems().get(entry.getKey()));
                        }else{
                            System.out.print("" + sumByRemainder.get(i) + j + " ");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: *"The wrong is at line.."* This is not an answer as seen below, so much as additional information for the question. Please [edit] the question to add that info, then delete the 'answer that is not' below.

Answer (score 0):

Length of 1 means there is only an element at index 0 - so you should do something like (i - 1)

Comment: This, is no an answer, not need to put as answer, and I know when appear, but in my case why?

Comment: @Richard this answer in not entirely wrong, since your loop is going up to `i <= rows` and we know that Java indices mostly are 0-based (assuming that `rows` has the correct value, *unfortunately* not posted). Also there is no access when `i == 0`, so the assumption that using `get(i-1)` solves the problem, isn't that bad

Answer (score 0):

As some of the variables you have used seems unknown here for the other people like me, I think this code snippet is the culprit for your problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
     System.out.print(sumByRemainder.get(i) + " ");
     for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
      //... your code
    }
}
```

You can try the loops limit like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.out.print(sumByRemainder.get(i) + " ");
            for (int j = 1; j < columns; j++) {
            // you code here
      }
}
```

Just give a check in your looping limit for both of the loops.